# ALC - Ontology consistency checking

Tags: owl, ontology, reasoning, description-logic

I have to check whether the following ontology is correct using the ALC tableux algorithm.

```
A ⊑ ∃s.¬B
C ⊑ A ⊓ B
C(x)
C(y)
s(x,y)
```

So first i use `C ⊑ A ⊓ B` to label x and y with A and B. So x and y now have the lables A,B and C. Then i use the ⊑-rule for `A ⊑ ∃s.¬B`:

```
¬A ⊔ ∃s.¬B
```

Since ¬A cant be true for x and y, ∃s.¬B musst be true. So i use ∃-rule that says that if there is no successor of s with label ¬B you add this node. So there is now a node e.g. z that is a sucessor of x and y and has the label ¬B.

Am i right with appyling the ∃-rule here? So in my conisderations the ontology is consistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the ontology is consistent. Your application of ∃-rule is almost correct in that yes, you need to introduce a new named individual as `s`-successor of `x`, say `z` - as you have done. **And** you have to also introduce a new named individual as `s`-successor of `y`, say `w`.

Thus, you have to introduce 2 new named individuals. You cannot reuse an introduced named individual as successor for 2 different individuals. The reason for this is that in a larger ontology, `x` and `y` may have other assertions or axioms that place additional constraints on them which may cause an inconsistency if you assume they have the same `s`-successor.