# OWL limitation: repeating variables

Tags: owl, ontology

I read this text:

"In OWL, there is a prohibition against repeating the appearance of a variable in a class axiom (for example, one cannot axiomatize the class of all barbers who shave themselves)".

Could someone point out a reference to learn about this limitation of OWL?

I would link to have a reference about this limitation of OWL. Thanks.

Comment: Can you state where you have read this?

Comment: I would like to receive some suggestions for reference. I don't have one.

Comment: You state in your question: I read this text "....". Where have you read it? This is helpful to understand the context of your question.

Comment: It is a blog from an ontologist at a University.

Comment: Then you can supply the link to the post.

Comment: Here it is: https://www.jneilotte.com/2020/06/modeling-rights-in-owl/

Answer (score 1):

This has been an issue in the first version of OWL. OWL 1 was based on the description logic SHOIN. OWL 2 is based on the description logic SROIQ which includes self reference. See the paper [the even more irresistible SROIQ](https://cdn.aaai.org/KR/2006/KR06-009.pdf).

I.e., you can state `Barber ⊑ ∃shaves.Self`

In a reasoning context, reasoning algorithms that are based on creating a model will make sure that individuals are not re-used. See my answer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76479645/alc-ontology-consistency-checking/76501502#76501502).

Comment: Many thanks; I will read the references.